# Tomcat 8 Http status 404 The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, web-deployment, tomcat8

I am using Tomcat 8, Spring and Maven.
I tried every solution given on Stackoverflow, but nothing worked.
My project get build successfully using Maven install.
The project gets successfully deployed in Tomcat. But when i make a request from browser to my project welcome page, i got Http Status 404 with description "The Requested resource is not available.

Here is my project structure:
[image]

Here is my web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">


  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/application-context.xml 
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And Here is my application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:core="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.7.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.bng.monitor" />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties"/>

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<mvc:resources location="/resources/css/**" mapping="/css/**"/>
<mvc:resources location="/resources/img/**" mapping="/img/**"/>
<mvc:resources location="/resources/js/**" mapping="/js/**"/>
</beans>
```

And below is the pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>***</groupId>
  <artifactId>MonAppWeb</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0</version>
  <name>MonAppWeb Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
        <spring.security.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.Final</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.Final</version>

        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>

        </dependency>
        <!-- EXCEL -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0.RELEASE</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.53</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160212</version>
    </dependency>     
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>mwa</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

And when i make a request from browser, i got the following warning message on tomcat console.

> Nov 03, 2016 6:12:13 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
>   WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/mwa/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
>   Nov 03, 2016 6:12:17 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
>   WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/mwb/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

And Http Status 404 on the browser.

Please help me out.

Comment: Is there any file under view folder with name *mwa*?

Comment: Nothing like that. Just jsp files with other names.

Comment: Problem is this For 404 not found

Comment: Mwa is the name of web application. Not any jsp

Comment: I heave few suggestions here: 1) delete entire `<welcome-file-list>` and `<init-param>` tag from `web.xml`. 2) Introduce a method in a controller class with `@RequestMapping("/")` and `return "index"`. 3) Move `index.jsp` to `views` folder.

Comment: @Arvind Did the Same. No Luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to copy manually all the jar file which were described in pom.xml to the lib folder of the Tomcat. And it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Solution – Add Jersey Library in Deployment Assembly

1. Right Click on Project's Properties (Alt+Enter)
2. Choose Deployment Assembly
3. Add jars
4. click Apply